# Seleccionar todos los archivos de una carpeta que sean de un tipo dado

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy buscando la forma de buscar de forma recursiva sobre una carpeta (que explore directorio y subdirectorios) archivos para poder ser subidos con AngularJS Upload, pero lo importante es en-listar los archivos y buscar en una carpeta local. Es decir, una función que devuelva en un array, por ejemplo, los archivos mp3 encontrados en una carpeta especificada, no me interesa tanto la parte de subir.

La idea es realizarlo en AngularJS si fuera posible o bien por JavaScript o jQuery tal vez. ¿Alguien sabe algo? Estaría bueno también que si encuentra archivos de nombre iguales solo tome uno no ambos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder buscar en todo un directorio y subdirectorios de uno en particular se puede realizar, de la siguiente manera:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('SubirArchivos', function($scope, $http, $parse) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.files = [];

  //a partir de aqui el codigo no funciona como deberia
  $scope.upload = function(element) {
    //aqui comienza el codigo de funcion para subir archivos
    console.log("intentando subir");
    angular.forEach(element[0].files, function(item) {
      console.log("intentando subir");
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('file', item);
      $http.post(item.url, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
        }
      }).then(function(success) {
        console.log("subido " + success.data.data);
        return success.data.data;
      });
    });
    // aqui finaliza la funcion encargada de subir archivos         
  };

});

app.directive('ngFileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.ngFileModel);
      var isMultiple = attrs.multiple;
      var modelSetter = model.assign;
      element.bind('change', function() {
        var values = [];
        /*if (files != null)
         element.push(files);*/
        angular.forEach(element[0].files, function(item) {
          if (item.name.endsWith("mp3")) {
            var value = {
              name: item.name,
              size: item.size,
              url: URL.createObjectURL(item),
              _file: item
            };
            values.push(value);
          }
        });

        scope.$apply(function() {
          if (isMultiple) {
            modelSetter(scope, values);

          } else {
            modelSetter(scope, values[0]);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>prueba</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="SubirArchivos">
    <input type="file" webkitdirectory directory ng-file-model="files" multiple />
    <button type="button" ng-click="upload();">Subir archivos</button>

    <p ng-repeat="file in files">
      {{file.name}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

De esta manera se puede seleccionar un directorio y este seleccionara todos los archivos y solo obtendrá los que son terminados en mp3